# What type of city-structure can survive a shield volcano?

Tags: construction, architecture, volcanoes

So I have a continent by the name of Sho. It is highly inspired by Asia, but will have a few mixes in the fray to give it my own touch. There is a specific people that live near a shield volcano.

I've chosen shield volcano because I am aware that their eruptions are much more gentle, **(which I understand can still be quite destructive)**. The people of this nation have built a city specifically around the shield volcano in a way to keep the lava flow (when it does erupt) from over running the city.

**They live near this volcano as they believe it is blessed by their deity (some believe the volcano itself is the center of creation. Some believe it to be the creator/their god).**

The city is not directly on the volcano, but close enough that they would need a specific type of wall, or ducts. This is a race is human. Currently, their technology is steam inclusive, but, this is based on the earlier chapter in their history.

**What can I use as a model when "constructing" this city?**

**edit** I did a little digging as to why a civilization might build near a volcano, and found a few reasons that I had not thought of before. Soil. Apparently ancient civilizations built their homes near a volcano because of rich soil, the beauty aspect, as well as possibly geothermal energy later on. So, it isn't such a crazy idea to build near a volcano. And, once the advent of their steam revolution came, it would explain why they may stick around.

Comment: Why do they live near an active volcano?

Comment: Its a holy site.

Comment: **On** the mountain, or **near** in on a plain?

Comment: What does "bounds of reason" mean?  What are you asking us to do?  Identify the mental state you should be in?

Comment: If it's holy, erect a temple and live somewhere else.  That's what everyone else does when their deity is a dangerous bit of the environment.

Comment: Welp. Not these folks. These people are hardy, intelligent, stubborn, and in some people's eyes, foolhardy. But, they've come up with a way to live there with minimal issues. Some peoples live in dangerous places, go through measures that common sense may go against.

Comment: "*But, they've come up with a way to live there with minimal issues.*"  Apparently not, since "they" are asking us how to do it.

Comment: Let's be more specific.  What's the tech level?  What type of stone is near by?  What religious prohibitions are there (can a wall be taller than the temple)?  How far from the top of the valcano are they?  How many people?  How thick is the city ring?  Is access to the summit important?  How old is the city?  Is dying during construction of defenses considered martyrdom?  How tall is the tallest building?  Does it rain?  If so, how often and on which side of the mountain?  Where is their agriculture?  Where is their water supply?  Do they trade with other cities?

Comment: A given: lava will flow whether you want it to or not.  But you don't want it to flow where you want to do stuff (live, travel, grow stuff, etc).  So build **big** trenches to redirect the lava *somewhere else*.

Comment: And how often does the volcano erupt?

Comment: @RonJohn, I was thinking the same thing, but they'd just fill with lava (which cools into rock).  This city would be constantly digging trenches.  It's hard to imagine its ability to economically support the effort.

Comment: @JBH Well, lets say, Chinese/Japanese tech at around the 17th century. The island they live on, is basically the shield volcano, which means it would cost more to pick up and leave after generations of living there. The volcano has been dormant for some years, but not long ago enough that these people wouldn't have found a way to get around it. I'm not sure the exact distance, as I got this idea from watching a documentary a while ago. I remember that there were instances in which lava flow would be slow enough to walk from. It would sometimes go over the highways.That enough info to work off?

Comment: @JBH "* It's hard to imagine its ability to economically support the effort.*"  Right, which is why it's a dumb idea to build near a volcano.

Comment: @RonJohn's being a bit caustic, but he's also right. People don't build directly on volcanos for a reason.  It's nearly impossible to stop the destruction, there's no water, and your food sources are miles away.  "Believers" don't last long and the fire god is soon forgotten.  And a shield valcano is the worst solution because it's shallow.  The lava will quickly layer up over the top of anything you build to block or divert it.  Unlike water, a layer of rock is always left behind.  The less devoted of the flock would quickly move to the plains. (*continued*)

Comment: OK, I just changed what I was going to say.  This won't work.  The lack of arable land and a water source makes this impossible.  Periodic destruction ensures no genetic tendency to try again.  A volcano that erupts so rarely that the community survives a long time obviates your question, and people would tend to trust that "god" was protecting them and stop building anything to protect themselves.  Sorry.

Comment: Well. If that is your folks answers, I'm still gonna find a way to make it possible. This story is fantasy based, so I may have to fudge a little and use magic, even if it isn't feasible in our world. Although, I think a good place to look would be Hawaii. There is one there I can think of, that has people living nearby.

Comment: @RonJohn I wish I could downvote your comments some times. This question is perfectly valid and a great example of a good WB question. It has a premise, and an issue to be solved to further the worldbuilding. What more do you want?!

Comment: @dot_Sp0T "*What more do you want?!*" Practicality.  Intelligent people (that's what OP wrote in a comment describing them) build cities *far* from volcanoes that are active enough for the populace to remember that the smoking mountains are active volcanoes.  When JBH and I say that, OP gets miffed.

Comment: @RonJohn then why dont you join a practical community such as UrbaneEngineering or Physics instead of a phantastical community that is WorldBuilding? This is not about *practicality*, it is about finding solutions to problems encountered when building one's own world!

Comment: @dot_Sp0T if you want phantastical, don't ask where something comes from.  Just *assume it to be true*, and if your story is good, readers will accept it.  OP is -- essentially -- asking why The Force works, wanting us to come up with a reasonable answer, like "midichlorians".  Well, we didn't ask the question, and OP's readers won't ask the question either.

Comment: Given the constraints we were given, yes, those were our answers.  It's nothing personal, but I literally couldn't come up with a way to save the city under the rules I was given.  Magic, obviously, changes everything, but so would providing the rest of the answers to my list (comment #8).  Especially the issue of distances.  Magic may be your only answer, but thinking through the backstory will help.  And remember, the word "near" in your research usually translates to "miles from the summit" and rarely "in the likely path of lava."

Comment: @RonJohnare we referring to the same question? The question I have read, 3 times now, is asking about an engineering solution to preventing a city around a shield volcano from being destructed by lava flow.I did not see it asking for reasons for people living there in the first place. In fact it even provided these reasons.

Comment: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-5077575/The-world-s-floating-city-set-2020-build.html so you can run from eruptions.

Comment: @Renan I think you copied the wrong link. Unless you meant to link to floating city design article. Why are you linking to a floating city design article?

Comment: I suggest looking at the recent Hawaii eruptions. Some of the video clips I've seen have had slow moving masses of lava. You can try picture what defenses would work well for something like [this](https://youtu.be/R2D23AlZmt8)

Comment: @EveryBitHelps if the city floats, it can sail away from eruptions.

Comment: @ViktorCogandGear uh, I  think I take the part about earth walls/barricades in my answer back. [Article on How to Stop a Lava Flow](https://www.forbes.com/sites/robinandrews/2017/03/29/how-to-stop-a-lava-flow/#2143c2bc29ec)

Answer (score 8):

Many modern people live on active shield volcanoes, Hawaii for instance is nothing but a large shield volcano, the key is to live ias far from the the actual crater and active areas as possible. this is not hard shield volcanoes are far bigger than people think.  Earthen dams are also useful in protecting settlements although eventually they will be overwhelmed. But this is rarely an issue since laval flows are not that common. Keep in mind large scale construction or excavation on a shield volcano can be tricky as they can trigger land slides which can create new eruptions in new places on the volcano.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into construction methods in flood-prone areas. Specifically building on stilts as well as ram filled earth-dykes etc.

This is assuming periodic small eruptions. For large eruptions, I suggest they pray to their deity.

I believe a history of living in the area would make sense if you follow a logical progression in defensive capabilities.

At first the people migrated around the volcano whenever it was erupting. Avoiding the dangerous areas and settling in a new location still on the slopes of the beloved deity.

Then they slowly become stubborn (really holy) and want to build a temple to their beloved that will withstand her (it's a female deity right?) ...hiccups. So they try a few different temples.

First one made of finely carved woods from all over the island. Unfortunately it burnt to ashes on the next lava flow in the area.

The second attempt they built a level of stone and then the finely carved wooden temple on top of that. Unfortunately that also caught alight on the next flow. The lava was stopped for a short time by the stone level but the stone was not thick enough as the lava gathered and accumulated in the vicinity before flowing off on the sides. The wooden temple also caught fire just from the excessive heat of the nearby lava. The locals learnt two things from this, when lava is obstructed, it grows in height before finding a new outlet and wood can burn even if not in direct contact with the heat source.

So they try again. This time they try and elevate the temple on multiple stone pillars. This allows the lava to flow mainly unobstructed and it doesn't gather and grow in height. After a few attempts, the design of the pillars incorporates various features such as wider on the side where the lava is most likely to flow from (incase the stone actually melts and gets eaten away), directional buttresses to direct flow in certain directions etc.

Either at the same time as developing the pillar design they also start building walls. They want to have some village halls and grain stores etc near their temple. Ie they are developing a settled village/town design rather than roaming around the volcano slopes.

The first walls are earthern embankments. After a few failures they realise you need a sharp slope on the outside and a thick gentle slope on the inner wall. Stone lining the sharp outer bank helps. The lava still grows if obstructed for large lengths so they figure out that they should build their walls V shape, not curved. This allows the lava to be pushed into a direction the villagers want. But a thin V shaped village design is not ideal.

After awhile the villagers want to expand. They build a second wall. And then a third. (The temple always has the most protection). They think they are clever, and leave a lined gap between each chevron to allow tempoary access to the flow. They line this gap with straight walls running through the length of their village. I don't know if this ends in disaster but it probably will. Once the lava has cooled and solidified the villages will have to either build more walks or try and take a pick ax to the stone to clear their protection features.

They then realise it's best to have a series of protection chevrons further away from their growing village. These chevrons will be placed in sequence so that they take up the slack etc. The main village having a further protective wall of some design.

**In summary,** The end result is that important buildings are built on stone stilts with protective buttresses. The most impirtant could be completely made of stone, or at least the lower levels. They are typically placed in the most protected areas directly behind the chevron walls. There are large open streets  to act as emergency funnels as well as further directional wall features inside the village/city to direct any lava that does make it into the area.

I'll try find some diagrams later to help explain my thought processes.